# JavaScript JSON Object arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js

Folks, I need to generate the following .json file and return to the browser:

```
"hosts": [
    {
        "project": [
            {
                "service": [
                    {
                        "role": [
                            {
                                "env": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Her blog",
                                        "cmd": "ssh username@blog2.example.com"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Her foo",
                                        "cmd": "ssh username@blog2.example.com"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

I am lost at how to loop through several local lists and generate this Object. I loop through a few lists to instantiate the Object like so:

```
_.each(instances, function (instance) {
    _.each(projects, function (project) {
        _.each(services, function (service) {
            _.each(roles, function (role) {
                _.each(environments, function (environment) {
                    if (_.isUndefined (projectObject[project])) {
                        projectObject[project] = {};
                    }
                    if(_.isUndefined(projectObject[project][service])) {
                        projectObject[project][service] = {};
                    }
                    ...
               });
```

In the next iteration, i build objects of each instance, but they dont show up in the browser, ie its an empty array, not an object.

```
_.extend(projectObject[project][service][role][environment],i); //doesnt work
```

As you can see, the requirement is to have Arrays of Objects.

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: 1. `instances`, `projects`, `services`, `roles`, `environments` are all arrays of strings, aren't they? If so, how they are related to each other?

Comment: 2. Do `hosts`, `instances` and `projectObject` refer to the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

To simplify things look at this, lets say you have this object:

```
var Myhosts = {"hosts": [
{
    "project": [
        {
            "service": [
                {
                    "role": [
                        {
                            "env": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Her blog",
                                    "cmd": "ssh username@blog2.example.com"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Her foo",
                                    "cmd": "ssh username@blog2.example.com"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
]}
```

To get the name and cmd of the env you do this:

```
Myhosts.hosts[0].project[0].service[0].role[0].env[0].name === "Her blog" 
Myhosts.hosts[0].project[0].service[0].role[0].env[0].cmd === "ssh username@blog2.example.com" 
Myhosts.hosts[0].project[0].service[0].role[0].env[1].name === "Her foo"
```

So if you have more than one object in any of the arrays, where you see [0] just replace 0 with a variable like x and loop through each dimension. Let me know if this helps.